# The correct way to say how reading books help you forget

Tags: sentence-construction

I wonder which one is correct.

- Reading book is the good way in order to forget something.
- Reading a book is a good way to forget something.

I saw the second sentence on a Skype account.

Comment: Welcome to ELL and thank you for your question. Unfortunately, we need more information before we can answer it well. Please use the [edit] link to tell us what you think is incorrect in your sentences. Also, please take a few minutes to review our [**tour**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages. They will help you to write a better question.

Comment: The [Details, Please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) meta post might be helpful as well. It's hard for us to know which is the correct way to say something when it's not even clear what you are trying to say. (That all said, the second sentence seems pretty good, but the first has a lot of problems.)

Comment: When you say "account holder", do you mean *yourself?* The first of your examples certainly doesn't look like anything even an *uneducated* native speaker would ever say.

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing **in order to** in the first sentence, and therefore it is ungrammatical.  The second sentence is OK.

We {*do* something} **in order to** {achieve a goal or an end}.

Your statement, "Reading ...*is*", is not analogous to {do something}.

We {turn on a light} **in order to** {see better}.

We {read a book} **in order to** {learn new things}.

We {kick the ball into the corner of the net} **in order to** {get it past the goalie}.

We {take a ferry} **in order to** {get across the river}

We {take a deep breath} **in order to** {stay underwater for one minute}.

Comment: I think we can read a book in order to forget, too. (It took me a minute to grasp this, but I think the context would be if you are trying to forget about something – like you just went through a painful breakup with a significant other, or your sports team just lost a championship game. In that case, reading a book would be a good distraction.) But you're right when you say that the first sentence is a botched mess. (We might say: _Reading a book is the best way to forget about something_, or: _You can read a book in order to forget something_ – but not what the OP wrote.)

Comment: Strictly to satisfy my own curiosity, why do you use braces here?